# Pegar elemento criado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou gerando uma tag A dinamicamente em um arquivo AJAX puro, sem Jquery. O código:

```
 if(xhr.status == 200){

  console.log(xhr.responseText);
  let resposta = xhr.responseText;
  resposta = JSON.parse(resposta);

  let x = document.querySelector('#resposta')
  resposta.map(item =>{

    x.innerHTML += '<a value='+ item.id +' class="descricao-resposta" 
  id="resposta-selecionada">'+ item.descricao +'</a>'
  });
```

Meu problema é que estou precisando capturar essa tag A depois para fazer um evento com ela, estou tentando capturar desta forma.

```
var btnResponde = document.querySelector('#resposta-selecionada');
btnResponde.addEventListener('click', function(evento){

evento.preventDefault();
respondeExercicio();
});
```

Mas no console diz que o meu addEventeListener está vindo null, ou seja, não está encontrando o código que eu estou gerando dinamicamente. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você esta criando mais de um botão certo?

Comment: Na verdade estou criando só o da tag A e tentando capturar ele depois de criado com o addEventeListener @WictorChaves

Comment: Vale lembrar que não pode ter 2 id's iguais no html, logo se o codigo dentro de `if(xhr.status == 200){` correr 2 vezes não vai funcionar como esperado. Assim como é necessário dar comportamento extra em relação ao click, a elementos que são posteriormente adicionados.

Comment: Em que momento você adiciona o evento? Por que não o adiciona dentro do `resposta.map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo para exemplificar melhor, desta forma o evento funciona normalmente:

```
let x = document.querySelector('#resposta');

x.innerHTML = '<a href="#" data-value="1" class="descricao-resposta" id="resposta-selecionada">teste</a><br/>';

var btnResponde = document.querySelector('#resposta-selecionada');

btnResponde.addEventListener('click', function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    respondeExercicio();
});

function respondeExercicio(){
    alert('ok');
}
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/uts27ejk/7/

Agora eu adicionando dois botões:

```
let x = document.querySelector('#resposta');

x.innerHTML = '<a href="#" data-value="1" class="descricao-resposta" id="resposta-selecionada">teste</a><br/>';
x.innerHTML += '<a href="#" data-value="1" class="descricao-resposta" id="resposta-selecionada">teste</a><br/>';

var btnResponde = document.querySelector('#resposta-selecionada');

btnResponde.addEventListener('click', function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    respondeExercicio();
});

function respondeExercicio(){
    alert('ok');
}
```

Você pode observar, que o segundo botão não funciona, isso ocorre porque não podem existir dois botões com o mesmo id, então ele só atribui o evento ao primeiro botão.

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/uts27ejk/9/

Você pode resolver desta forma:

```
let x = document.querySelector('#resposta');

x.innerHTML = '<a href="#" data-value="1" class="descricao-resposta" >teste</a><br/>';
x.innerHTML += '<a href="#" data-value="1" class="descricao-resposta" >teste</a><br/>';

var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.descricao-resposta');

[].forEach.call(elementos, function(elemento) {
  elemento.addEventListener('click', function(evento){
      evento.preventDefault();
      respondeExercicio();
  });
});

function respondeExercicio(){
    alert('ok');
}
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/uts27ejk/18/

Assim você utiliza somente a class(já que ela pode ser repetir) faz um forEach para percorrer todos os elementos e atribuir o evento desejado.

Comment: Mas eu estou criando só um mesmo e não está dando

Comment: Mas o que esta acontecendo, o botão não aparece, ou ele não executa o evento click?

Comment: Ele é gerado, aparece no front, mas não consigo selecionar com o document.querySelecotr... que é a segunda parte do código que postei

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "selecionar"?

Comment: Tipo, quando faço esse código para colocar a ação na botão que estou gerando com a tag A, ele diz que o evento vem nulo... ele não está encontrando a tag que está sendo criada, mesmo ela aparecendo na tela.. var btnResponde = document.querySelector('#resposta-selecionada');
btnResponde.addEventListener('click', function(evento){

evento.preventDefault();
respondeExercicio();
});

Comment: Já tentou atribuir este código abaixo do "x.innerHTML ...", eu não sei como esta a ordem do seu código original, mas você esta recebendo uma informação, esta informação pode esta vindo de forma assíncrona, ou seja, você pode esta atribuindo o evento antes mesmo dele ter sido criado, então colocando abaixo de onde ele esta sendo criado o problema pode ser sanado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76369/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-francis-vagner-da-luz).